# web scraping with beautifulsoup getting error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to Python and mainly need it for getting information from website.

```
def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.example.com'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'c5'}):
            href = link.get('href')
            time.sleep(0.3)
            # print(href)
            single_item(href)
        page += 1
def single_item(item_url):
    s_code = requests.get(item_url)
    p_text = s_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p_text, "html.parser")
    upc = ('div', {'class': 'product-upc'})
    for upc in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'upcNum'}):
        print(upc.string)
    sku = ('span', {'data-selenium': 'bhSku'})
    for sku in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'fs16 c28'}):
        print(sku.text)
    price = ('span', {'class': 'price'})
    for price in soup.findAll('meta', {'itemprop': 'price'}):
        print(price)

    outFile = open(r'C:\Users\abc.txt', 'a')
    outFile.write(str(upc))
    outFile.write("\n")
    outFile.write(str(sku))
    outFile.write("\n")
    outFile.write(str(price))
    outFile.write('\n')
    outFile.close()

spider(1)
```

What i want to get is "UPC:813066012487, price:26.45 and SKU:KBPTMCC2" without any span, meta or content attributes.I attached my output below
Here is my output:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWoH0.jpg)

Where do i do wrong ?
Hope someone can figure it out! Thanks!!

Comment: but what output do you expect? also, could you fix the indentation of the code so that the structure is more clear? I guess the entire block below `def single_item` should be indented?

Comment: First grab all links and then go to each links and scrape (upc, price, sku).

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: Expected output is like this
813066012487
KBPTMCC2
26.45

Comment: Add what you are trying to get to your question.

Comment: Can you add a link to the actual site?

Comment: i just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you want is in the div attribute *data-itemdata*, you can call `json.loads` and it will give you a dict that you can access to get what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/accessories/ipp/100/mnp/25/Ns/p_PRICE_2%7c0/ci/20861/pn/1/N/4005352853+35").content, "html.parser")


for d in soup.select("div[data-selenium=itemDetail]"):
    data = json.loads(d["data-itemdata"])
    print(data)
```

Each data dict will look like:

```
{u'catagoryId': u'20861',
 u'inCart': False,
 u'inWish': False,
 u'is': u'REG',
 u'itemCode': u'KBPTMCC2',
 u'li': [],
 u'price': u'26.45',
 u'searchTerm': u'',
 u'sku': u'890522'}
```

So just access by key i.e `price = data["price"]`.

To get the *UPC* we just need to visit the items page, we can get the url from *h3* with the *data-selenium* attribute:

```
for d in soup.select("div[data-selenium=itemDetail]"):
    url = d.select_one("h3[data-selenium] a")["href"]
    upc = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").select_one("span.upcNum").text.strip()
    data = json.loads(d["data-itemdata"])
```

Not all pages have a UPC value so you will have to decide what to do, if you just want products with UPC's first check if the select finds anything:

```
for d in soup.select("div[data-selenium=itemDetail]"):
    url = d.select_one("h3[data-selenium] a")["href"]

    upc = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser").select_one("span.upcNum")
    if upc:
        data = json.loads(d["data-itemdata"])
        text = (upc.text.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic, i get everything but one thing is missing. Each item has UPC, in order to get that needs to get each link and get that. I can't figure that out.

Comment: now i'm getting this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: That is because https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1222834-REG/cherry_g85_23200eu_2_stream_3_0_keyboard_black.html has no UPC value

Comment: Thanks, Works perfect.